# How to add a rowid in sqlite matched selected result?

Tags: sqlite

When i query with :

```
select code,volatility  from big_sh  order by volatility asc;
```

I get right result,when adding  rowid in the statement ,the rowid is matched with table big_sh,can i create a new rowid matched with my new result of select ?

```
select rowid,code,volatility  from big_sh  order by volatility asc;
```

Comment: Do you mean that you would like each row returned to be sequentially numbered, such that the first row has "ID" 1, the second 2, the third 3, and so on, regardless of each row's actual ID?

Comment: yes,it is my meaning.

Comment: There is no simple way using just SQLite3 to achieve this. The solution will either be horribly inefficient or involve temporary tables. You should consider using a counter variable in the loop you use to read the results in your program.